# Golang - unmarshal only specific XML nodes

Tags: go

I´m currently trying to learn golang by converting an existing project to "go".
This involves working with XML data.
The documentation about un-marshalling looks good so far, but I need only certain parts of the XML I´ve to process.
The already existing project is using xpath and xslt to archive this. 
Unfortunately "go" doesn´t seem to have this.

The documentation has this as example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
type Email struct {
    Where string `xml:"where,attr"`
        Addr  string
    }
    type Address struct {
    City, State string
    }
    type Result struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Person"`
        Name    string   `xml:"FullName"`
        Phone   string
        Email   []Email
        Groups  []string `xml:"Group>Value"`
        Address
    }
    v := Result{Name: "none", Phone: "none"}

    data := `
        <Person>
            <FullName>Grace R. Emlin</FullName>
            <Company>Example Inc.</Company>
            <Email where="home">
                <Addr>gre@example.com</Addr>
            </Email>
            <Email where='work'>
                <Addr>gre@work.com</Addr>
            </Email>
            <Group>
                <Value>Friends</Value>
                <Value>Squash</Value>
            </Group>
            <City>Hanga Roa</City>
            <State>Easter Island</State>
        </Person>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %#v\n", v.XMLName)
    fmt.Printf("Name: %q\n", v.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Phone: %q\n", v.Phone)
    fmt.Printf("Email: %v\n", v.Email)
    fmt.Printf("Groups: %v\n", v.Groups)
    fmt.Printf("Address: %v\n", v.Address)
}
```

How is it possible to filter on an attribute to get only the "home" Email Nodes (and child nodes, if they exist)?
Something like

```
Email   []Email  `xml:"Email[@where='home']"`
```

Comment: As far as I recall Unmarshal decodes the data to your struct with a minimum of interpretation. Filtering on attributes is not possible. This would be a pretty trivial thing to implement in your own code though.

Comment: There are xpath libraries. This blog post discusses some of them and some issues. http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/07/efficient-xpath-for-go

Comment: Thanks. I´ve managed to use libxslt from go, so I can use a similar workflow as in the existing project.

Comment: @Hotte Could you describe your solution by providing an answer and approving it? The question is still in the Unanswered queue...